# Assembling relations of multiple models in rails - impossible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, models

Let's say I have three models.

`User`, `Tool` and `Work` (actually the models are different but for simplicity sake it's these guys). Now..

I `User` is given `Tool` and `Tool` does some `Work`.

```
User has many Tools
every Tool belongs to one User

Tool has many Works
every Work was done with single Tool
```

I can successfully get `User.tools` but I can't get the Works done by user.

I tried:

```
User.tools.each do |tool|
  tool.works.each do |work|
    <%= work.id %>
  end
end
```

but that did not exactly go as expected (multiple id's of Works a User has done), instead I got error...

What do I do wrong?

Comment: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column works.tool_id does not exist at character 48: SELECT "works".* FROM "works"  WHERE "works"."tool_id" = $1

Comment: Did you get my answer ? I think you can go that way, I described. Because the way you describe your need, it perfectly suits to the *many-to-many* model.

Comment: Yes, it was perfect. My mistake was to think that rails want to know that Works belong to User. My mistake. The more you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a *many-to-many association* for the same :

```
class User <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tools
  has_many :tasks , :through => :tools, :source => :works
end

class Tool <  ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :works
end

class Work <  ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tool
end
```

Now you can do :

```
@users = User.all
@users.each do |user|
  user.tasks do |task|
    <%= task.id %>
  end
end
```

Make sure, the migration is correct. All the *foreign_key/primary key* relationship should be correct, otherwise you will get *undefined column error*. Check the [`#has_many` official doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) to understand the options I passed with the `has_many` method call.

Comment: This is perfect! My mistake was to think that rails want to know that (Tasks) belongs_to :user. The more you know...